# How To Move Row To New Sheet Automatically If Anything But A Specific Value

Tags: javascript, triggers, google-sheets, eventtrigger

I'm curious if I could have a row move automatically to another sheet if the value is anything but a certain value. So essentially if someone changes the status on the sheet "Follow-Ups" from the value of Follow-Up to any of the other values, it moves it to the sheet "Motivated Sellers". I'm trying to avoid scripting it by listing all the values other than Follow-Up, but I'd rather not in case I decide to add other values later and forget to come back and add it to the script. Here is the script I am currently using:

```
function onEdit() {
  Utilities.sleep(60000);

  // moves a row from a sheet to another when a magic value is entered in a column
  // adjust the following variables to fit your needs
  // see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/ehoCZjFPBao/discussion

  var sheetNameToWatch = "Garage Sale List";

  var columnNumberToWatch = 1; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = "Processed";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Garage Sale List Archive";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();


  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
}
```